# arduino error: too few arguments to function 'int getMode(int, int, int, int, int)'

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, led

I am working on getting a led array set up for a project. I got an array of LEDs to change depending on a pin changing voltage, but I can't add any more pins.

When I try, the compile fails with 
error: too few arguments to function 'int getMode(int, int, int, int, int)'

```
void setup() {
  delay(3000);
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, LED_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
  pinMode(pin5, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(pin6, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(pin7, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(pin8, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(pin9, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
int getMode(int d5, int d6, int d7, int d8, int d9) {
  int rtn = 1;`k`
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have 2 functions with identical headers (same function names, and same parameters). You must either rename one of the `getMode()` methods, or make it take different parameters.

When you have 2 functions that take in exact same parameters, and a function in that class is called, the computer does not know which one to run.

Comment: That was a goof in when i pasted the code. The code pasted twice which explains the double calls. They do not exist in the code and i have changed the question to match the code correctly